# Insert a characters in NSString

Tags: iphone, nsstring

I am having difficulty with subj.

I have NSString text, contains "SLOVO", and i need that NSMutableString* currentRequest contain "%t%e%x%t%".
I trying in cycle:

```
     [currentRequest appendFormat:@"%c%%", [text characterAtIndex:i]];
```

It's working fine, BUT if text contain for example "Rüdiger", i mean non latin symbols, then currentRequest contains full trash !

I've see decide is use 
(void)insertString:(NSString *)aString atIndex:(NSUInteger)anIndex
but i think it is no right way.
May be know right way ?

thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I may have misunderstood, but I think the issue with `appendFormat` is a mismatch between the `%c` format specifier and the return type of the `characterAtIndex` method.

Method `characterAtIndex` returns a `unichar`, whereas `%c` expects an 8-bit `unsigned char`.  Use `%C` (uppercase C) instead in your format string.

Some Apple developer docs for reference:

- [String Format Specifiers](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004265-SW1)
- [NSString characterAtIndex method](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-characterAtIndex_)